# How to insert historical data on their respective partitions

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a database that has records stretching back to 2014 that I have to migrate it to BigQuery, and I think that using the partitioned tables feature will help on the performance of the database.

So far, I loaded a small sample of the real data via the web UI, and while the table was already partitioned, all the data went to a single partition with the date that I had run the query in, which was expected, to be fair.

I searched the documentation sites and I ran into [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables#addressing_table_partitions), which I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for.

I have two questions:

1) In the above example, they use the decorator on a `SELECT` query, but can I use it on a `INSERT` query as well?

2) I'm using the [Python client](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/bigquery-usage.html) to connect to the BigQuery API, and I while I found the `table.insert_data` method, I couldn't find anything that refers specifically to insert in the partitions, and I'm wondering if I missed it or I will have to use the query API to also insert data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Investigated this a bit more:

1) I don't think I've managed to run an `INSERT` query at all, but this is moot for me, because..

2) Turns out that it is possible to insert in the partitions directly using the Python client, but it wasn't obvious to me:

I was using this snippet to insert some data into a table:

```python
from google.cloud import bigquery

items = [
    (1, 'foo'),
    (2, 'bar')
]
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = client.dataset('<dataset>')
table = dataset.table('<table_name>')
table.reload()
print table.insert_data(items)
```

The key is appending a `$` and a date (say, `20161201`) to the table name in the selector, like so:

```python
table = dataset.table('<table_name>$20161201')
```

And it should insert in the correct partition.

Comment: When trying to do as you did, I have a BadRequest: `You can only stream to partitions within 31 days in the past and 16 days in the future relative to the current date.` Any possible workaround ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it turned out that we didn't move forward with implementing BigQuery in our project and I didn't run into this particular issue when I was experimenting with it. It might be more useful if you post a new question and link to this one.

Comment: Got your point, doesn't worth opening a new question imho. Workarounds are proposed in GCP BQ documentation,  best advice is using bq as command line...